# Trying to update version of ibm db2 provider .getting error : OLE DB ERROR : ole DB or odbc error . The specific procedure could not be found

Tags: db2, ssas, cube, olap-cube

Trying to update version of IBM Db2 provider.
Steps I'm following:

- Open connection string of any data source .
- Enter server name
- In provider option at top: click on drop-down, select "Native OLE DB" and "IBM OLE DB provider 11.1.1".

Test connection is working.

When trying to reprocess a dimension,getting error :

> OLE DB ERROR : ole DB or odbc error . The specific procedure could not be found

Comment: When you say "When trying to reprocess a dimension" what SQL is actually being run? Does the error message tell you what procedure could not be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is keys messages of your case:

- Update DB2 to V11.1
- Test connection is working
- Error: OLE DB ERROR : The specific procedure could not be found.

Based on the above, the symptom can be caused when Db2 reads unexpected
old version of OLE related dll file(s) somehow.  But the test connection 
does not read/need these OLE related files so can be done without any error.

In this unexpected situation, we may need to remove old unnecessary version files 
completely and place new version files only.  So it is suggested to uninstall
Db2 once, reboot machine and then install Db2 again.

FYI, here is the starting page for uninstalling Db2:

**Uninstalling Db2 database products**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/c0059726.html

Hope this helps.